# Laravel 5.2 Image Not Showing

Tags: php, image, laravel-5

My image location:

```
public_html/storage/app/public/img
```

My PHP code:

```
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/app/public/img/$product->image") ?>">
```

The image does not show. Please help me, anyone.

Comment: By default, storage/app is not visible outside, you have to run php artisan storage:link to make the symbolic link between public and  storage/app. (at least if you have a standard installation)

Also, try to var_dump your code to see what's really shown.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 5.2 docs, your publicly accessible files should be put in directory

> storage/app/public

To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from **public/storage** to **storage/app/public**

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/laravel/public/storage
```

Create in your view an URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
 echo asset('storage/app/public/img/$product->image');
```

Answer (score 0):

create a symbolic link for the storage directory using the artisan command

**php artisan storage:link**

you can access your image through url helper like 
--> url('storage/app/public/img/$product->image')